# Having trouble setting the DIRS url in Django TEMPLATES

Tags: python, django, django-templates

have created a folder templates in my project's main folder and am  trying to set a url for django to look for templates in and I am getting the following error:

> ```
> 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
>  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
> ```

In my settings.py file I have inserted the following code:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The version of django is 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

`BASE_DIR / 'templates'`

Here [slash operator helps to create child paths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators)(similarly to `os.path.join()`), and this operator is implemented for Path objects not for strings.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("mypath")
>>> print(p / "child")
mypath\child
```

So in your case you can convert `BASE_DIR` to a `Path` object.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path(BASE_DIR) / 'templates'
```

OR

you can use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` function to combine both path strings